# Codeigniter form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, validation

I have the following html code below that will upload images from client side to my php apache server.
Backend, I have used the codeigniter form validation. However, after using the code below, user's images cannot be uploaded in to my server. If I comment the `form_open(......)` code `<?php $prevURLPATH=urlencode($prevURL); echo form_open('newPost/createNewPost/'.$userID.'/'.$username.'?prevURL='.$prevURLPATH); ?>`, my form actually works(those images get posted successfully), but of course it is done without codeigniter validation. 
There,
is it possible to be able to post images and using codeigniter validation at the same time??

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="container">
  <?php echo validation_errors("<div style='color:red;'>","</div>"); ?>

<?php $prevURLPATH=urlencode($prevURL); echo form_open('newPost/createNewPost/'.$userID.'/'.$username.'?prevURL='.$prevURLPATH);  ?>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9 page-content">
       <div class="inner-box category-content">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
              <form id="newPost" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                   action="<?php echo base_url(); echo MY_PATH;?>newPost/createNewPost/<?php echo $userID.'/'.$username.'?prevURL='.urlencode($prevURL); ?>"> 
               <fieldset>
                  ………….
…………………………………
        <div class="form-group row">
                       <label class="col-md-3 control-label text-center" for="textarea"> 
                           <i class="icon-camera-1"></i><abbr title="Min. 1 picture required."><?php echo $Picture;?></abbr><font color="red">*</font></label>
                       </label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                           <div class="mb10">
                               <input id="image" name="images[]" class="file" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
                                 <div id="uploadImgError">
                                 </div>
                           </div>
                               <p class="help-block">Add up to 5 photos. Use a better image of your product, not catalogs.</p>   

                       </div>
                   </div>


         div class="form-group row">
                       <label class="col-md-3 control-label text-center"></label>
                       <div class="col-md-8"> 
                               <button id="submit-upload-form"  class="btn btn-primary btn-tw" onclick="setup(); return false;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>Submit</button>
                           <button id="validate" hidden="true" type="submit"></button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
               </fieldset>

         </form>


           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

The follow is the javascript call that will submit the form:

```
function setup()
{
    var myform = document.getElementById("newPost");

            $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('show');

            setForm(function(data)
            {
                if(data == true)
                {
                    var formData = new FormData(myform);
                    for (var i=0; i<fileList.length; i++){
                        formData.append('filelist[]', fileList[i]); 
                    }
                    $('#image').fileinput('clear');
                    $('#image').fileinput('disable');
                    $('#Adtitle').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#soldqty').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#descriptionTextarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#tagsInput').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#submit-upload-form').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#price').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //console.log (formData.get('image'));
                    $.ajax({
                        xhr: function()
                        {
                            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            //Upload progress
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                              if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total*100;
                                //Do something with upload progress
                                $("#upload-progress-bar").width(percentComplete+"%");

                              }
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                        },
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); echo MY_PATH;?>newPost/createNewPost/<?php echo $userID.'/'.$username.'?prevURL='.urlencode($prevURL); ?>",
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success:function(msg){
                            $("#modal-text").html("Your post has been successfully uploaded.");
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $("#modal-text").html("Your post will be reviewed and go on live within the next 24 hours.");
                                $('#fwd-btn').css("display", "block");
                                $('#fwd-btn').css("margin", "auto");
                                $('#progress-bar').css("display", "none");
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return data;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you are opening multiple forms. one from CI function and another one from plain html

Comment: So if I use the CL function to initialize the form, I don't need HTML 5 form?

Comment: yes. Form_open will produce html form code only.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

I have below jquery javascript function in the submit button that will use URL to do form submit. How to change it??

```
function setup()
{
    var myform = document.getElementById("newPost");

            $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('show');

            setForm(function(data)
            {
                if(data == true)
                {
                    var formData = new FormData(myform);
                    for (var i=0; i<fileList.length; i++){
                        formData.append('filelist[]', fileList[i]); 
                    }
                    $('#image').fileinput('clear');
                    $('#image').fileinput('disable');
                    $('#Adtitle').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#soldqty').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#descriptionTextarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#tagsInput').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#submit-upload-form').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#price').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    //console.log (formData.get('image'));
                    $.ajax({
                        xhr: function()
                        {
                            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            //Upload progress
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                              if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total*100;
                                //Do something with upload progress
                                $("#upload-progress-bar").width(percentComplete+"%");

                              }
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                        },
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); echo MY_PATH;?>newPost/createNewPost/<?php echo $userID.'/'.$username.'?prevURL='.urlencode($prevURL); ?>",
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success:function(msg){
                            $("#modal-text").html("Your post has been successfully uploaded.");
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $("#modal-text").html("Your post will be reviewed and go on live within the next 24 hours.");
                                $('#fwd-btn').css("display", "block");
                                $('#fwd-btn').css("margin", "auto");
                                $('#progress-bar').css("display", "none");
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return data;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `form_open_multipart()` instead of `form_open()` but probably it won't be enough.

Form validation is not checking file inputs, I don't know why but I'm sure that. Because of that, you have to control it in your model.

You can use this structure:

```
if(empty($_FILES))
{
 return false;
}
else
{
  //some code here
}
```